# i cannot set my background images based on an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to set the background images of my divs based on an array
html

```
<div class="container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
</div>
```

i want to set each background image based on an array

```
var image_src = new Array ("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    $("div div div").css("background-image","url(" + image_src[i] + ")");
}
```

each source to each div

Comment: Voting to close because of multiple typographical errors that are too localized to be reproduced (see comment on answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong (the third div). Consider using each jQuery function like this:

```
var image_src = [ "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg" ];

$("div.container div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("background-image","url(" + image_src[i] + ")")
});
```

Comment: thank you  this was very helpful..i actually did use this in the first place but now i realize that the problem was with me not declaring new array.and the third div is just a copying mistake